# How to update an iOS widget from its parent app?

Tags: ios, swiftui, widget, widgetkit

Apple's *Reminders* app has a widget that shows all reminders in a list. When I open the app, add (or remove) a new reminder and close the app again, its widget immediately updates to reflect the changes I just made. I want the same behavior for my app, i.e. I want my app to trigger a live update for its widget.

[image]

I understand that widget updates are typically triggered through timelines that I specify in the widget's `(Intent)TimelineProvider`. So  I tried to return a single timeline entry with the current date in order to trigger a live update:

```
func getTimeline(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, 
                 in context: Context, 
                 completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {

    let entry = SimpleEntry(date: .now, configuration: configuration)
    let timeline = Timeline(entries: [entry], policy: .atEnd)
    completion(timeline)
}
```

(I also tried other policies without success.)

Additionally, I call

```
WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()
```

in my app whenever the widget needs to update. However, this doesn't work. The widget is not refreshed when I close the app.

What am I doing wrong and how can I trigger a live update for the widget from the parent app?

Comment: How does storage work? are you sure that the updates are available for the Widget when you call `reloadAllTimelines` an app group might be helpful for storage that way the main app and the extension can share the storage

Comment: Yes. I'm using Core Data with a shared App Group and only call `WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()` after  saving the managed object context. (As the app uses the same App Group and Core Data stack, the widget should show the same data as the app and the app shows the updates immediately.)

Comment: Do an `NSFetchRequest` in `getTimeline()` to get the new values. Then load the `SimpleEntry` with the new values there.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! It was a simple caching issue: I was fetching the same item with an `NSFetchRequest` from Core Data multiple times and in that case, Core Data won't update the result. A `viewContext.refreshAllObjects()` did the trick.

Comment: Could you please post a complete answer with the Provider code and SimpleEntry, as I need to achieve the same goal in my app triggering the widget update. Thanks.